# "creat" System Call in Unix

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

I am using creat system call to creat a file. The following is the program to creat a file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
void main()
{
    int fd=creat("a.txt",S_IRWXU|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
    printf("fd  = %d\n",fd);
}
```

So, At first time, the program creates a file named a.txt with appropriate permission. If I execute a.out one more time, the new a.txt will be created. But, the inode of the file remains same. How, it will be.

```
$ ./a.out
fd  = 3
$ ls -li a.txt
2444 -rw-r--r-- 1 mohanraj mohanraj 0 Aug 27 15:02 a.txt
$ cat>a.txt
this is file a.txt
$ ./a.out
fd  = 3
$ cat a.txt
$ls -li a.txt
2444 -rw-r--r-- 1 mohanraj mohanraj 0 Aug 27 15:02 a.txt
$
```

In the above output, a.txt have the content as "This is file a.txt". Once I execute the a.out, the new a.txt created. But, the inode
2444 remains same. So, how creat system call works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file already exists when you "create" it the second time, so it is truncated and keeps the same inode number.

Comment: From man page: `creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equal to O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`creat` only creates a file if it doesn't exist. If it already exists, it's just truncated.

```
creat(filename, mode);
```

is equivalent to

```
open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode);
```

And as specified in the [`open(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) documentation:

> **O_CREAT**
>   If the file does not exist it will be created.

Comment: The official Linux man-page on this is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: I know, same for me, this however does not increase linux.die.net's quality ... :-/. So I always add "man7" when gxxgling for (Linux) man-pages.